# Wrong sign in numerical integration, possible precision issue

Tags: c, numerical-integration

I need to integrate the following function:

[image]

where `z > 0`. The problem is that the integrand is very small for large `z` and high precision is required in the integration. So far, I have written the integrand as

```
double integrand__W(double x, double z){
    double arg = z*z/(4.0*x);
    
    double num = exp(arg+x)+1;
    double den1 = expm1(arg);
    double den2 = exp(x);

    num = isinf(num) ? arg+x : log(num);
    den1 = isinf(den1) ? arg : log(den1);
    den2 = x; //log(exp(x))=x
    double t1 = num-den1-den2;
    
    num = exp(x);
    double den = exp(x)+1;
    double t2 = isinf(den) ? exp(-x) : num/(den*den);
    
    return t1*t2;
}
```

For numerical integration, I'm using [Cubature](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature_(Multi-dimensional_integration)), a simple C-package for adaptive multidimensional integration:

```
//integrator
struct fparams {
    double z;
};

int inf_W(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval){
    struct fparams * fp = (struct fparams *)fdata;
    double z = fp->z;
    double t = x[0]; 
    double aux = integrand__W(a_int+t*pow(1.0-t, -1.0), z)*pow(1.0-t, -2.0);
    if (!isnan(aux) && !isinf(aux))
    {
        fval[0] = aux;
    }
    else
    {
        fval[0] = 0.0;
    }
    return 0;
}

//range integration 1D
    size_t maxEval = 1e7;
    double xl[1] = { 0 };
    double xu[1] = { 1 };

    double W, W_ERR;
    struct fparams params = {z};
    hcubature(1, inf_W, &params, 1, xl, xu, maxEval, 0, 1e-5, ERROR_INDIVIDUAL, &W, &W_ERR);
    cout << "z: " << z << " | " << W << " , " << W_ERR << endl;
```

where the integration over the semi-infinite interval is possible by a change of variables:

[image]

Analytically, I know that the integrated is non-negative, so the integral itself should be non-negative. However, I'm getting some incorrect results due to a lack of accuracy:

```
z: 100 | -3.97632e-17 , 1.24182e-16
```

In `Mathematica`, working with high precision, I can get the desired result:

```
w[x_, z_] := E^x/(E^x + 1)^2 Log[(E^(z^2/(4 x)) + E^-x)/(E^(z^2/(4 x)) - 1)]

W[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[w[x, z], {x, 0, ∞},
  WorkingPrecision -> 40,
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

W[100]

(* 4.679853458969239635780655689865016458810*10^-43 *)
```

**My question:** Is there any way to write my integrand such that I can reach the required precision? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the same question to a different [community](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/40405/41421), I got two suggestions that seem to work:

### Avoiding subtractive cancellation

Manipulate the integral a little bit first:

[image]

and then rewrite the integrand as

```
double integrand__W(double x, double z){
    double arg = z*z/(4.0*x);
    
    double t1 = log1p((exp(-x)+1)/expm1(arg));
    
    double num = exp(x);
    double den = exp(x)+1;
    double t2 = isinf(den) ? exp(-x) : num/(den*den);
    
    return t1*t2;
}
```

### Use of Exp-Sinh quadrature

This integration scheme is provided by the `Boost` library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/math/quadrature/exp_sinh.hpp>

using boost::math::quadrature::exp_sinh;
using std::exp;
using std::expm1;
using std::log;

int main() {
    exp_sinh<double> integrator;
    double z = 100.0;
    auto f = [z](double x) {
        double k1 = 1.0/(2 + exp(-x) +exp(x));
        double t = z*z/(4*x);
        double log_arg;
        if (t > 1) {
            log_arg = (1 + exp(-x)*exp(-t))/(1 - exp(-t));
        } else {
            log_arg = (exp(t) + exp(-x))/expm1(t);
        }
        return k1*log(log_arg);
    };
    double termination = sqrt(std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon());
    double error;
    double L1;
    double Q = integrator.integrate(f, termination, &error, &L1);
    std::cout << "Q = " << Q << ", error estimate: " << error << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are integration schemes which only use positive weights, resulting in nonnegative integral values if the evaluated function values of the integrand are all nonnegative. Some other integration schemes permit negative weights, resulting in a possibly higher accuracy for integration. Cubature probably uses one of those.

Your actual integral value is very close to 0 for z=100, and that's what you're getting, too, so there's really nothing wrong with the integration scheme. If you absolutely need nonnegativity, one option is to simply set the negative results to 0.

Answer (score -1):

I can't say much about the mathematics (i have a love/hate relationship with math) but higher precision *can* be achieved via `long double` and the related math functions in the standard math library.

But `long double` does not necessarily mean higher precision, dependend on your compiler and system architecture it could be simply a double or 80 bit extended precision or more.

**More info:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision

Comment: Increasing the precision will no do away with the problem in the integration scheme.